# Datazen server after restore not ready

Tags: sql-server, business-intelligence, windows-server-2012-r2, datazen-server

I have a problem with my Datazen and Windows Server 2012 R2.

So I installed Datazen server on another machine and did a full backup in order to restore the backup on the new datazen server.

I did it exactly like they told me to do in here [Datazen Backup & Restore](http://www.datazen.com/docs/?article=server/backup_and_restore), but it's not working.

I restarted the server but is still says: "Server not ready. We're sorry but your request cannot be completed at the moment. Please try again in a minute."

I also changed the InstanceID and DB Encryption Key.

Nothing works. Maybe there are some Datazen specialists here. :)

Thanks for help, pronax

Comment: Please use the "Post Your Answer" link at the bottom of the page to answer your question instead of editing it into your question.

Comment: @josliber Okay. So you just deleted the stuff I edited and now I don't remember the full detailed answer anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I talked with the support of Datazen and he told me to change the InstanceID and the DB Encryption Key in every single config file it appears.

So just go through your config files in the Datazen folder and change the InstanceID and the encryption key to the new values. AFAIK it must be round about 7 files.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to restore from a newer OS environment to an older one. For example, restoring to Windows Server 2008 R2 from a backup made from Windows Server 2012 is not permitted. If you were using Windows Server 2012 R2 then you can restore backup to Windows Server 2016 or  Windows Server 2012 R2.

Answer (score 0):

I was going through a restore procedure today and had the same problem. What I can suggest:

Check the permissions on the Data folder inside installation folder of Datazen. the user your Datazen Core Service is running with should have read/write permissions on it

change the instance id in all config files:

```
C:\Program Files\Datazen Enterprise Server\webapi\Web.config
C:\Program Files\Datazen Enterprise Server\viewer\Web.config
C:\Program Files\Datazen Enterprise Server\service\Datazen.Server.Service.exe.Config
```

the overall procedure would look like this:

```
net stop datazenrenderingservice
net stop datazendata
net stop datazen

cd "c:\Program Files\Datazen Enterprise Server\service"

rmdir /S /Q Data

mkdir Data
```

check permissions for core service user, also make sure you deleted all the data inside

replace instace id with instance id and encryption key of the old server in:

```
C:\Program Files\Datazen Enterprise Server\webapi\Web.config
C:\Program Files\Datazen Enterprise Server\viewer\Web.config
C:\Program Files\Datazen Enterprise Server\service\Datazen.Server.Service.exe.Config
```

restore

```
   Raven.Server.exe -restore -src "C:\Datazen\Backups\datazen-201604181-93fa5e38" -dest "C:\Program Files\Datazen Enterprise Server\data"

esentutl /d Data\Data

Datazen.Server.Service /console /shutdown

net start datazen
net start datazenrenderingservice
net start datazendata
```

make sure all services are running

Hope that helps a bit.

Answer (score 0):

- open a command prompt (as Administrator)
- Command: net stop datazen.Wait for the service to stop.
- Navigate to the Core Service folder ([installation folder]\service):
  cd c:\Program Files\Datazen Enterprise Server\service
- If the Core Service data folder ([installation folder]\service\Data)
  exists, delete it: rmdir /S /Q Data
- Create the Core Service data folder: mkdir Data
- Issue the restore command: Raven.Server.exe -restore -src [path to
  backup] -dest Data and wait for the message Esent Restore: Restore
  Complete(Raven.Server.exe -restore -src
  "c:\Datazen\Backup\datazen-2017022685719-36bd23b7" -dest Data)
- Make sure the Core Service is correctly restored by issuing the
  command: Datazen.Server.Service /console /shutdown. The service
  should start and then stop successfully.
- Start the Core Service: net start datazen

These steps definitely helpfull because i executed practically